# how to prove this limit is zero?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{\sqrt{1\times2}}{n^2+1}+\frac{\sqrt{2\times3}}{n^2+2}+\cdots+\frac{\sqrt{n\times(n+1)}}{n^2+n})=0$$

I tried to use $\sqrt{k(k+1)}\le\frac{2k+1}{2}$ or $k(k+1)=\sqrt{k}\times\sqrt{k}\times(k+1)\le\left(\frac{2\sqrt{k}+k+1}{3}\right)^3$ but nothing worked out. Can you show me some hint to deal with $\frac{\sqrt{k(k+1)}}{n^2+k}$ ? Thanks!

Comment: Stolz Cesaro tells that the limit should be $1/2$. There is a typo in the source from where the problem is taken.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? $$ \frac{n(n+1)}{2(n^2+n)} \leq \lim \leq \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2(n^2+1)}$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks! I posted the original question. It looks like i did it wrong at the first place:(  Can you show me some hint about this one?

Comment: @VladislavKharlamov . I was going to say that but you're 2 hours ahead of me. Simplest possible answer.

Comment: @VladislavKharlamov please don't post an answer on the comment. Comment is only for suggesting an improvement to the post, not for answering the question.

Comment: @AndrewT. This was not meant as an answer, because the author claimed that the limit is 0. And I logically asked why I'm wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The limit is not $0$, it is $1/2$. Observe that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2+i} < \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\sqrt{i(i+1)}}{n^2+i} < \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i+1}{n^2+i}$$

The limit of the left hand side is the same as the limit as the right hand.  By Squeeze theorem, the middle limit is also the same. So, it suffices to find the left hand limit.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2+i} \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2+n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(n+1)}{2n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

This gives $1/2$ as a bound from below. We obtain $1/2$ as a bound above by observing $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n^2+i} \leq  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i}{n} = \int_0^1 x \ dx = \frac{1}{2}$$

The last step is a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 4):

If you enjoy harmonic numbers, starting with 
$$\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{i}{n^2+i}  \lt \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sqrt{i(i+1)}}{n^2+i}\lt \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{i+1}{n^2+i}$$ you have
$$S_1=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{i}{n^2+i}=n+n^2\left(H_{n^2}- H_{n^2+n}\right)$$
$$S_2=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{i+1}{n^2+i}=n+(n^2-1)\left(H_{n^2}- H_{n^2+n}\right)$$ Now, using the asymptotics and continuing with Taylor series
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ for large values of $n$, you should have
$$S_1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6 n}-\frac{1}{4 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$S_2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{7}{6 n}-\frac{3}{4 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$